# adding datatable to a SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, datatable, version, addition

Is it possible to add a datatable to a database AFTER the implementation of a database in androids SQLite like it's possible on a mysql-database?! If I see it right, there's no way to do so, as you have to implement the datatable at the same time when you create the database, because of the database version concept of android. Do you know any solution for that!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible, all you need to do is to use [CREATE TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statement appropriately.

In Android, you will need to add this into onUpgrade method, something like this:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,
    int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    if (oldVersion < 1) {
        db.execSQL(
             "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable ("
             + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
             + "name VARCHAR(20)"
             + ")"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But, the "onUpgrade" method is only called, when I pass a newer Version to the dbhelper! Doesn't it?!

Comment: You can also create your table in `onCreate()`, and call onCreate() from onUpgrade(). But then always use `IF NOT EXISTS` clause

Comment: that doesn't change the situation, because both of them are only called, when you have a newer version. I want to dynamically add and delete datatables during runtime, but not delete other datatables. Or else the only way would be to create one database for each datatable.

Comment: well, nothing stops you from calling `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` anywhere in your code